# I am confused with Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am rookie into Java and I am directly thrown into Hibernate and Spring. I have attended some training classes and I am following documents online from random forums and trying to run a test project. I have some set of questions to be answered.

What is the latest version of Hibernate that has come and where do I download all the dependent jars in one place?

What is the latest version of Spring that is out there?

Any links/blogs that shows me to configure a hello world or a similar implementation would be of great help with the latest versions of Spring and Hiberante!!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [Google](http://tinyurl.com/674o3n9)?

Comment: @adarshr: Yes.. i got confused a bit and perhaps here i will get answers the way i expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you check out [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo). There is a [super duper quickstart](http://www.springsource.org/roo/start).

Although its touted for doing Code and JSP scaffolding I find its biggest benefit is setting up your project in a very canonical and java/spring best practice setup.

It will setup maven and all the dependencies you will need. The default Maven Pom file alone is a big time saver.

If you don't want to use Roo you can easily just strip it out of your Maven pom file after your done doing the initial scaffolding.

The other option is using a [Maven Archetype like AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) but I haven't used this in quite some time and I find Roo easier.

**What I don't recommend is wasting your time writing an Ant script and then trying to cobble together all the dependencies.**

Answer (score 2):

The project web page says it is [Spring 3.0.5 Release](http://www.springsource.org/download)

The project web page says it is [Hibernate 3.6.1 Release](http://www.hibernate.org/downloads)

[Hibernate and Spring tutorial](http://www.techfaq360.com/tutorial/spring/spring_hibernate.jsp)

Rest you will find using some web search like google.com or bing.com or altavista.com